# Arduino code — what's the use of while(0)?

Tags: c, arduino

```
const int buttonPin = 2;    
int buttonState = 0;        

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("1");
    buttonState=LOW;
    delay(20000);
      while(0);
  }
}
```

Basically the code works like this:

- the number of the pushbutton pin
- variable for reading the pushbutton status
- initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
- read the state of the pushbutton value:
- check if the pushbutton is pressed. If it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  send char 1 via Bluetooth:

I have an Arduino, HC 06 bluetooth module, a button and an app that makes a phonecall when the button is pressed (HC 06 send a byte, 1, to the app)

My question is, what's the `while (0);` for?

----ORIGINAL CODE----
    const int PirSensor = 2;
    int motionState = 0;

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(PirSensor, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  motionState = digitalRead(PirSensor);
  if (motionState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("1"); 
    motionState = LOW;
    delay(20000);
//    while(0);
  }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything, like that. Why did you put it there?

Comment: Because  I addapted my code from another that, instead of a button, it had an PIR motion detector. And i couldn´t understand what was the meaning of the while.

Comment: @PedroFerreita Can you please show the original example then?

Comment: The most common context in which you see `while (0);` is at the end of a `do { … } while (0);` loop.  I think it is fair to argue it is the _only_ context in which `while (0);` is useful.  As it stands, the empty body of the loop is never executed because the loop continuation condition is unconditionally false (zero).  An alternative which is commonly seen is an infinite loop — `while (1) { … }` and sometimes that will have an empty loop body.  This time the condition is unconditionally true (non-zero).

Comment: I have seen do{} while(0) used in pre-processor macros to guard against something but I can't remember what it was.  I think it was to make sure that multi-statement macros that got put behind if statements without braces like they were single lines would act right.

Comment: @orhtej2I added it to the question

Comment: @Delta_G: That's correct.

Comment: My guess is: you edit it to `while(1);` and it is guaranteed that the loop is only executed once. (and you can debug without entering a breakpoint). And the `while(0);` will be optimised out, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I am not mistaken in this case nothing.

In most computer programming languages, a while loop is a control flow statement that allows code to be executed repeatedly based on a given Boolean condition. The while loop can be thought of as a repeating if statement.

Note that if you do have a condition, a while loop must have an exit option, like this:

```
const int buttonPin = 2;    
int buttonState = 0;        

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("1");
    buttonState=LOW;
    delay(20000);
    int a =0;
      while(a==0){
        if (something)
          a=1;
      }
  }
}
```

Then on your chosen condition you will exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`while(0)` is most commonly used in macro definitions, specifically in those which are meant to be used like `void` functions or other instructions, like

```
#define inc(x) do { x = ((x)+1); } while (0)
```

The reason to use it is simply to make the use of the macro look like an invocation of a function by forcing the user to append a `;` to the macro invocation. In the above example,

```
inc(a)
a = a*2;
```

would cause a compile error due to the missing `;` after the `while(0)` the macro expands to, so you have to write

```
inc(a);
a = a*2;
```

which makes the code look more like `inc` was a function. Also, embedding the macro's code in a loop like this helps in preventing accidental use of the macro as an expression, akin to a `void` function. ( `a = ((a)+1)` is a valid expression, so `b = inc(a)` would be valid too (expands to `b = a = ((a)+1)`) if the macro did not contain the (semantically irrelevant) `while` loop.)